# Unable to publish jar to Gitlab package registry with gradle

Tags: gradle, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am trying to publish some jar artefacts on gitlab package registry but I get this error from the server :

```
Received status code 415 from server: Unsupported Media Type
```

Here is the publishing section of my build.gradle.kts :

```
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven"){
            artifact(tasks["bootJar"])
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url =  uri("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/my-group/-/packages/maven")
            name = "Gitlab"
            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials::class) {
                name = "Token"
                value = System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN")
            }
            authentication {
                create<HttpHeaderAuthentication>("header")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my gitlab-ci, I added a task for publish the artefacts :

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: gradle publish
  only:
    - master
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hi Dimitri, I'm new to GitLab and Maven. I need to publish JAR to GitLab package registry using Maven. Could you please help How can I achieve the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 35):

#### Quick answer

Replace your publishing url pointing to the group-scope with the one pointing to the specific-package-repository, e.g. on `gitlab.com`:

`https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<your-project-id>/packages/maven`

You need to replace `<your-project-id>` with your specific project-id of course.

Related to this a quote from [docs.gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#configuring-your-project-to-use-the-gitlab-maven-repository-url):

> Note: In all cases, you need a project specific URL for uploading a package in the distributionManagement section.

Or in other words: Only the **general repositories** section can use your groups-url for **searching** other **already published** artifacts! (I also had to understand that). So:

- you cannot **publish** to the group-package-store on gitlab, you can just **search** there.
- Publication goes always to the project-specific package-store, which will then be visible at group-scope too.

#### Example gradle config (kotlin-dsl)

```kotlin
repositories {
    mavenCenter()
    jcenter()

    // Here you USE the group api/v4 url for SEARCHING packages
    maven {
        name = "GitLab"

        url = uri("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/groups/my-group/-/packages/maven")
        credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials::class) {
            name = "Job-Token"
            value = System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN")
        }
        authentication {
            create<HttpHeaderAuthentication>("header")
        }
    }

}

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven"){
            artifact(tasks["bootJar"])
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            
            // here your PROVIDE the PROJECT-URI for publishing your package
            // in the project-specific package-space which is also visible at
            // the group scope above
            url =  uri("https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<your-project-id>/packages/maven")
            name = "Gitlab"
            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials::class) {
                name = "Job-Token"
                value = System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN")
            }
            authentication {
                create<HttpHeaderAuthentication>("header")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### More Info

There are multiple scenarios on how you may interact with the maven-repository-space on GitLab. The three switches are:

1. The place where you want to **look** for existing published packages

   - [project-scope](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#project-level-maven-endpoint) (`https://.../api/v4/projects/<project-id>/packages/maven`)
   - [group-scope](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#group-level-maven-endpoint) (`https://.../api/v4/groups/<group-id>/-/packages/maven`)
   - [instance-scope](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#instance-level-maven-endpoint) (`https://.../api/v4/packages/maven`)
2. The authorization-method you want to use

   - [PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#authenticate-with-a-personal-access-token)
   - [DEPLOY_TOKEN](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#authenticate-with-a-deploy-token)
   - [CI_JOB_TOKEN](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#authenticate-with-a-ci-job-token)
3. The place where your want to [**publish** your package](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#uploading-packages)

   - this must always be a specific project-url (`https://.../api/v4/projects/<project-id>/packages/maven`)

Comment: Follow your reply and I got 403: Forbidden instead. Tried all 3 kinds of token (with their respective headers, ofc). Wonder what's the problem here?  
I'm on gradle 6.5 and Gitlab 13.6.1

Comment: @ThanhNhan I managed to get all kinds of errors, but not 403. From my failures, I think that if you get 415 it means that you are not publishing to a valid package repository, while 401 means that you are using the correct URL but didn't set up authorization properly - which is the main issue I had: I was working with examples from other repos where you needed to use `<username>` and `<password>` which is not the case for gitlab - please pay careful attention to the `settings.xml` examples in the authorization documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Guss. Actually, I was using the wrong URI. The 403 was from another service that hosted on the same server with different port.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, there are also other reasons for the response status `415 Unsupported Media Type`:

I ran into the same error message while trying to publish to the project repository. The error that I made was to use the URL-encoded path of the project instead of the project ID in the repository URL.

From the [Gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#project-level-maven-endpoint) (emphasis added):

> For retrieving artifacts, use either the URL-encoded path of the project
> (like `group%2Fproject`) or the project's ID (like `42`). **However, only the
> project's ID can be used for publishing.**

This is the `build.gradle.kts` configuration that worked for me on my self-hosted Gitlab instance for publishing a Spring Boot fat JAR:

```kotlin
plugins {
    /* ... other stuff ... */

    `java-library`
    `maven-publish`
}

publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("bootJava") {
            artifact(tasks.getByName("bootJar"))
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            val projectId = System.getenv("CI_PROJECT_ID")
            name = "Project Name"
            url = uri("https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/${projectId}/packages/maven")
            credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials::class) {
                name = "Job-Token"
                value = System.getenv("CI_JOB_TOKEN")
            }
            authentication {
                create<HttpHeaderAuthentication>("header")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most important thing is to make sure you've enabled archives in your project:

1. Go to Project Settings

[image: Go to Project Settings]

2. Expand Permissions

[image: Look for permissions]

3. Switch on "Packages"

[image: Switch on Packages]